# VBA - call function without return variable

Tags: vba, excel

i have function:

```
Function importCSV(fileName As Variant) As Boolean

' some code
' no importCSV = TRUE

end Function
```

i call this function

```
importCSV (fileName As Variant)
```

every do OK, bud when a modific function.

```
Function importCSV(fileName As Variant, linkToHeader As Boolean) As Boolean
    ' some code
    ' no importCSV = TRUE

end Function
```

i cant call function like this

```
importCSV (fileName As Variant, TRUE)
```

VBA detect syntax error and a must call

```
a = importCSV(fileName As Variant, TRUE)
```

Why?

Comment: You can dispense with the brackets `importCSV fileName, TRUE` otherwise Excel tries to evaluate the contents of the brackets.

Comment: Check if "a" Variable is Boolean

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To avoid assigning the return value to any variable you can use `call` keyword

```
call importCSV(fileName As Variant, TRUE)
```

Additionally you can call the function this way:

```
importCSV fileName:="File name", linkToHeader:=TRUE
```